# What will I have to take care of myself, if I decide to use leaflet in Angular without the ngx-leaflet library?

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

Recently, I found a blog entry where it is shown how to use a leaflet with Angular without using ngx-leaflet: https://codehandbook.org/use-leaflet-in-angular/

What will I have to take care of myself if I do not use ngx-leaflet?
For now, basic functionalities such as map display, click event, markers, circles and polygons work, but I worry about more advanced functionalities.

I know that I can have problems with ChangeDetection and Selectors, but does anyone know in which other places I would have problems and what would these problems consist in?

Comment: Please don't use tags that are irrelevant with your question (like in this case google-maps, openstreetmap etc)

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if this solution is correct or will not generate problems at
>   a later stage. Will this solution cause errors in more advanced
>   functionalities?

Most likely you wont have issues, considering the fact that the approach in the article works with the lib in the way that [its documented](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map), eg.using the `L` constant.

Although something that isnt mentioned in that article is the use of the `@types/leaflet` package. That way you can profit from strong typing, and avoid the `declare var L` stuff.

> Maybe ngx-leaflet is not needed anymore?

It never was, so to say. The library simply *abstracts* the use of leaflet by providing an angular directive. So its basically a more angular-ish way of working (IMO better).

You should choose what suits you best:

**You dont want to add an extra dependency or see no gain from its usage (ngx-leflet)?**

Fine, then just dont make use of it.

**You prefer to use angular components, directives or services in order to hide lower level js libraries?**

Fine, then make use of an utility lib like ngx-leaflet.